# disable scrollPosition while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a program that uses `scrollPosition`= `UITableViewScrollPositionTop` to display the selected row on top. But when i scroll down and click on any other row, scroller  scrolls back to the first selected row. is there any way i can disable the `UIScrollPositionTop` while i am scrolling. Or Any other solutions please?

This method is called after regular intervals to highlight (select) the rows.

```
-(void)highlightcell:(int *)rows {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:*rows inSection:0]; 
[tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIScrollView delegate to detect when scroll is started and when it has stopped, then use a flag to keep scrolling states as below:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    isScrolling = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    isScrolling = NO;
}
```

Then in your method:

```
-(void)highlightcell:(int *)rows {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:*rows inSection:0]; 

if (isScrolling) {
    [tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES     scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
else {
    [tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES     scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It still doesn't work. whenever i scroll down and try to click on any row, it scrolls back to the current highlighted row.

Comment: It worked now. I used scrollViewDidEndAccerlating method with scrollViewDidEndDragging and a BOOL values as you recommended. Many thanks man

Answer (score 0):

try to do this..

```
    Self.Table_small.scrollEnabled=NO;
```